# Selecting which fields to show in address composite control

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

By default, when creating a new account, the composite address control displays three lines for entries (*Street_1*, *Street_2* and *Street_3*). It looks really inappropriate in our scenario so I'd like to remove one of there. In fact, I'd like to gain a full control of what's shown and what's hidden.

According to [this blog](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/sonomapartners/archive/2013/12/11/manipulating-composite-fields-in-dynamics-crm-2013.aspx), we can resolve this by application of business rules. I don't like it one bit.

We need to rely on a condition from one field to affect the others for the rule to kick in. It feels like giving up to the stupid computer and cheating, without actually gaining control. And lastly - it'll be a huge number of rules bouncing around back and forth in my case. Baaad karma.

How can I control the contents of a composite control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article mentions that hiding a field on a form, hides it on the composite address control as well.  Not sure if there is some other magic going on behind the scenes, but if there isn't, just add javascript to hide the field.

Here is a little helper function:

```js
setVisible: function (controlName, visibility) {

    // Do we need to be here?
    if (!controlName) { return; }
    if (!Xrm.Page.getControl(controlName)) { return; }

    // Set visibility.
    Xrm.Page.getControl(controlName).setVisible(visibility);
},
```

Comment: Yupp, that's what I did. In fact, it's even cleaner to do it using business rules (the new happy-happy-stuff in 2013) than using JS. However, my question is whether it's possible to configure a composite control's fields design-wise, instead of hiding them. I fear it's not possible which mean I'll have to write a bunch of JS calls or business rules. And I'm lazy...   :)